# how to check availability of custom image attribute

Tags: magento

i know this question is just being asked many times but i have some problem in custom image attribute i create new custom image(image180) attribute with magento admin & using this code to get image in frontend & this code working properly & showing image how to correct this & thanks in advance

```
<div class="rotate"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image180'); ?>"></div>
```

but i have to check if this image is avabile then run the code if not avaible don't run this code because if this attribute not avaible fir specific product the product page is not load & show the error & i am using this code to check avability of custom image but not working what going wrong

```
<?php if ($_product->getimage180()):?>
                <div class="rotate"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image180'); ?>"></div>
                <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please you try this

getImage180()):?>
                helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image180'); ?>">

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`if($_product->getData('image180')!=null && $_product>getData('image180')!='no_selection')`

instead of `if($_product->getimage180())`

And if you use `$_product->getimage180()` then also it is invalid.

It should be `$_product->getImage180()`